# Filter the domain list for Windows Logon

Tags: windows, domain, login

Is there a way to filter the domains that are available to log into on a Windows Workstation?

I know I can use the following adm policy setting to set it to one domain, but I need it to show two of the five that we have available:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon.
```

The 2 keys to change are:

`ShowLogonOptions` - set to 0 to hide the domain list &

`DefaultDomainList` - set this to the domain you need to logon to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter it, you can only hide it.  It's built and automatically populated from the list of domains that are trusted by the domain your machine is a member of.